# Multiple external files in web.config?

Tags: .net, iis-7, web-config

I need to do something like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Three" value="NumberThree"/>    
</appSettings>
<appSettings configSource="One.config"/>
<appSettings configSource="Two.config"/>
```

This gives me an error: `Sections must only appear once per config file.`

That kinda sucks :( Just wondering: Is there any way/setting I can enable to do something like this? (IIS7, .net 3.5SP1)

I have very little control of the web.config and can't modify the existing appSettings element, only add new items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurations have a set inheritance hierarchy.

Checkout [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

EDIT: Another one:
[How to: Configure Specific Directories Using Location Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178692%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help for you particular scenario.
Have a look at the `file` attribute on `<appSettings>`

```
<appSettings file="Two.config">
  ...
</appSettings>
```

In `Two.config` you can then do the same to point to `One.config`